# How to cache content in Varnish?

Tags: nginx, caching, nginx-reverse-proxy, varnish, varnish-vcl

How can we cache contents (like game updates, files, ...) with varnish caching ?
I also want to reverse proxy the https connections with no caching.
I did it before with Nginx but now I want switch to Varnish.

I searched the google too but there is no example/configuration to do this thing with dnsmasq etc. !

I tried to do it myself by getting the host header and proxy to that with Varnish but I can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

### The Varnish basics

Your initial question is quite vague unfortunately, so the level of detail with which I can answer that question will be quite limited.

Out of the box Varnish will respect HTTP `Cache-Control` headers and other HTTP conventions. The standard caching behavior of Varnish is explained in the following tutorial: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/varnish-builtin-vcl/.

Deviating from the standard behavior requires writing VCL code. Here's a basic VCL template you can use: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/example-vcl-template/. This VCL template caters to some of the basic needs of a real-world website or application.

Customizations can be done in the VCL file of course.

Here are some tutorials on how to install Varnish: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/#installations

### HTTPS

If you want Varnish to handle `https://` traffic, you'll need to terminate TLS using a TLS proxy. I suggest using [Hitch](https://hitch-tls.org/). Here's a tutorial: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/terminate-tls-varnish-hitch/

If you've installed Hitch with `PROXY` protocol support, here's how you bypass the cache for `https://` traffic (as you requested in your question):

```
vcl 4.1;

import proxy;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto == "https" || proxy.is_ssl()) {
        return(pass);
    }    
}
```